# Golang syntax error : assignment mismatch: 4 variables but 2 values

Tags: go, syntax-error, variable-assignment

The code below produces a compilation error.

After grappling with this error for hours, I still can't figure out what to do with this.

Here is an simplified example which produces the same error:

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
)

func a() (int,bool) {
    return 3,true
}
func b() (int,bool) {
    return 4,true
}
func main(){
    if k,ok1,h,ok2 := a(),b(); ok1 && ok2 && k==3 && h==4 {
        fmt.Printf("ok!")
    }else{
        fmt.Printf("fail!")
    }
}
```

Obviously, `k,ok1,h,ok2 := a(),b();` leads to this error.
But I don't know how to 
modify this code.

For some reason, I can't mov this assignment statement out of if-else block.
Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Comment: If that _would_ be allowed it would be dangerous as it could lead to subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant section in the language spec:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments

In short:

```
k,ok1,h,ok2 := a(),b()
```

is invalid go syntax. The "...right hand operand is a single multi-valued expression...". Above, you have two expressions. You have to do the assignment separately:

```
k, ok1:=a()
h, ok2:=b()
```

And the if statement becomes:

```
if ok1 && ok2 && k==3 && h==4  {
}
```

If you don't want those variables outside that scope, do this:

```
{
  k, ok1:=a()
  h, ok2:=b()
  if ok1 && ok2 && k==3 && h==4  {  
  }
}
```